# Show caption on chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I'm in need of some help.  I'm using chart.js graphics, with the "doughnut" model. I need the values ​​to be printed on the chart, both the absolute value and its percentage in relation to the amount (as shown in the model below).

Please could someone help

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("tempoGastoNaLoja");
var myDoughnutChart2 = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',    
    data: {
        labels: [
    "10min",
    "30min",
    "45min",
    "1h",
    "1h30",
    "2h+"
        ],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [80, 42, 38, 21, 15, 18],
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#ffd833",
                    "#f4b12d",
                    "#e88b28",
                    "#dd6422",
                    "#d13e1d",
                    "#c61717"
                ],
                hoverBackgroundColor: [
                    "#ffd833",
                    "#f4b12d",
                    "#e88b28",
                    "#dd6422",
                    "#d13e1d",
                    "#c61717"
                ]
            }],
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,         

        }

    }
});
```

[image: Example]